# React Bootstrap 5 Carousel with multi-items CarouselItems

Tags: reactjs, typescript, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, bootstrap-5

I am learning React+Typescript and am new to Bootstrap and currently working on the task to create a Bootstrap Carousel with multi-item CarouselItems - I want to display on one slide 4 items, side-by-side horizontally in one row - which I finally did, but I want also be able to slide prev or next only 1 item (so in theory around 25% of slide), not the full slide - does someone has any idea how this can be solved?

below is my code from vsc

```
import { Carousel, CarouselItem, Container } from "react-bootstrap";

type CarouselItemType = {
  text: string;
  backgroundColor: string;
};

const items2: CarouselItemType[] = [
  { text: "item 1", backgroundColor: "blue" },
  { text: "item 2", backgroundColor: "green" },
  { text: "item 3", backgroundColor: "yellow" },
  { text: "item 4", backgroundColor: "red" },
  { text: "item 5", backgroundColor: "pink" },
  { text: "item 6", backgroundColor: "violet" },
  { text: "item 7", backgroundColor: "blue" },
  { text: "item 8", backgroundColor: "green" },
  { text: "item 9", backgroundColor: "yellow" },
  { text: "item 10", backgroundColor: "red" },
  { text: "item 11", backgroundColor: "pink" },
  { text: "item 12", backgroundColor: "violet" },
];

const reduceHelper = (
  accumulated: CarouselItemType[][],
  current: CarouselItemType,
  index: number
) => {
  const groupIndex = Math.floor(index / 4);
  if (!accumulated[groupIndex]) accumulated[groupIndex] = [];
  accumulated[groupIndex].push(current);
  console.log(accumulated);
  return accumulated;
};

const CardCarousel = () => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Carousel>
        {items2.reduce(reduceHelper, []).map((item2, index) => (
          <CarouselItem
            key={index}
            style={{
              padding: "10px",
              borderColor: "black",
              borderWidth: "2px",
              borderStyle: "solid",
            }}
          >
            {item2.map((it, ind) => (
              <Container
                key={ind}
                style={{
                  display: "inline-block",
                  backgroundColor: it.backgroundColor,
                  width: "20%",
                  height: "200px",
                  margin: "0 2.5%",
                }}
              >
                {it.text}
              </Container>
            ))}
          </CarouselItem>
        ))}
      </Carousel>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default CardCarousel;
```